# Write variables to executable

Tags: c++, variables, executable, patch

I go straight to the point.

I have 2 C++ executables, let's call them Program 1 and 2.

Program 2 has some variables, like `Var1`, `Var2` and `Var3`, which all have the value 0.

Now what I want to do is that when I open Program 1 I want to be able to rewrite these variables in Program 2, so that it sets `Var1`to 1 for instance.

A simple "patcher" function, like some would say.

Comment: Windows: [`WriteProcessMemory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: May be you either didn't get the concept of executables, or how to organize your functionality within classes. For me the most natural approach would be to have a class that holds these variables and have a program option class to provide these via command line parameters.

Comment: @H2CO3 Might work, but is this really good advice?

Comment: @g-makulik Not sure. Question rather obscure.

Comment: @H2CO3 Agreed! There's not a lot of information, but smells like re-usage and inheritance concepts ...

Comment: No, what I want to do is write to the program in inactive state, so the variables will stay the same, no matter how often the program is being opened.

So I once use Program 1 to set Var1 of Program 2 to 1 and every time I open Program 2 it'll tell me that Var1 is 1 and the rest is 0 unless I set the rest to 1.

Comment: @user2404495 What's the reason (by design) why you have program1 and program2 and not just a single executable?

Comment: Are you familiar with the idea of a parameter file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need some form of inter-process communication (IPC) to be able to communicate between the two executables.

Your options here will depend on your target system and libraries available, maybe you can provide some more information here?

Examples of IPC methods are as follows:

- File
- Shared memory
- Sockets
- Message queue
- Semaphore
- Pipe, Named pipe